# laravel get object data from JSON response giving undefined

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

i'm using ajax to get data from model by controller every thing is running nice i think and when i check with console.log(response) i get

```
Object {buyTemps: Object}
```

and in side the object  i found All data inside the array up to now every thing is good

ajax

```
     $(".buy-tr").click(function(e){ 
    var 
      data = {}, 
      $row = $(this).closest("tr"),            // Finds the closest row <tr> 
      $tds = $row.find("td:nth-child(1)");     // Finds the 2nd <td> element
    $.each($tds, function() {                  // Visits every single <td> element
        data={buyId:$(this).text()};                     
    }); 
  //  $(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked', true); 

    $(".buy-tr").click(function(e){ 
    var 
      data = {}, 
      $row = $(this).closest("tr"),         // Finds the closest row <tr> 
      $tds = $row.find("td:nth-child(1)");  // Finds the 2nd <td> element
    $.each($tds, function() {               // Visits every single <td> element
        data={buyId:$(this).text()};                     
    });  
    $.ajax({
        url : "/buy/selectTable",
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : 'json',
        data : data,
    success : function(response) { 
            console.log(response);

       $('#buyItem-table tbody').empty();
        $.each(response,function(index, v){
           $('#buyItem-table tbody').append(                                          

                  "<tr><td>"         +  v.buyItemTempId   
                      + "</td><td>"  +  v.itemName    
                      + "</td><td>"  +  v.itemExpire    
                      + "</td><td>"  +  v.buyPrice                          
                      + "</td><td>"  +  v.buyBox   
                      + "</td><td>"  +  v.itemPacking                           
                      + "</td><td>"  +  v.buyQty       
                 + "</td></tr>" );          

           });


    },
    error : function(response) {
      swal("error"); 
    }
```

at my controller

```
     public function selectItemTable()
    {

        $buyId = Input::get('buyId'); 
        $buyTemps = DB::table('vbuytemp')->where('buyId',$buyId)->paginate(10);      
         return Response::json(compact('buyTemps'));    

}
```

the consol.log(v)

```
  Object {total: 1, per_page: 10, current_page: 1, last_page: 1,       next_page_url: null…}current_page: 1data: Array[1]0: Objectbarcode: "08815408"buyBox: 30buyId: 2buyItemTempId: 2buyPrice: "2.500"buyQty: 90itemExpire: "2018-01-04"itemId: 2itemName: "Panadol Extra tab"itemPacking: 2minQty: 1roofId: 1sellingForm: 1__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]from: 1last_page: 1next_page_url: nullper_page: 10prev_page_url: nullto: 1total: 1__proto__: Object__defineGetter__: __defineGetter__()__defineSetter__: __defineSetter__()__lookupGetter__: __lookupGetter__()__lookupSetter__: __lookupSetter__()constructor: Object()hasOwnProperty: hasOwnProperty()isPrototypeOf: isPrototypeOf()propertyIsEnumerable: propertyIsEnumerable()toLocaleString: toLocaleString()toString: toString()valueOf: valueOf()get __proto__: get __proto__()set __proto__: set __proto__()
```

the result  all table cell fill with undefined

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that when you make your ajax call you get all of the data back correctly in a json object? If so, it means that your Laravel controller must be working correctly and this is some problem with your javascript that you are using to render those results. Are you sure your result has all of the properties you are referencing in every single instance (i.e. buyItemTempId, itemName, etc.)?

Comment: yes each field as it is value  in side array [1]

Comment: Object
barcode: "08811509"
buyBox: 10
buyId: 1
buyItemTempId: 1
buyPrice: "3.000"
buyQty: 20
itemExpire: "2016-01-04"
itemId: 1
itemName: "Panadol COLD+FLU Daily  tab"
itemPacking: 2
minQty: 1
roofId: 1
sellingForm: 1

Comment: I would suggest running a `console.log(v)` inside your `$.each` loop and make sure that `v` is always in the format that you just described without a missing property in *any* instance of the it. If that looks correct, then I'd try breaking out string that you are appending with into its own variable and eventually breaking each property line into its own variable to try to isolate any missing data. Honestly, your code looks fine to me so unless there is something you are not printing, I feel that there must be some missing data.

Comment: thanks any way ,, since i upgraded to window 10 a lot of thing goes wrong lately
i tried since yesterday and i couldn't find any answer

Comment: Upgrading your OS really shouldn't have any effect on this. So `console.log(v)` looked correct inside the loop? Could you edit your answer to contain a full version of the response returned by the ajax request?

Comment: i update the post just check above

Comment: That was very helpful and showed me the issue. You are not looping at the right level. Check out my answer below. Please let me know if that fixes things.

Comment: Hey so I see you added a lot more code which is great. However, I was really meaning could you add the full *response* from the ajax call? So far you have been copying from the console inspector in your browser which causes a lot of formatting issues, so that is why I requested you hit your ajax url manually in the browser - this will return just the text of the json response.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are looping through response data at the wrong point. When you call `$.each` you are actually looping through all of the pagination metadata (total, per_page, etc.). The actual data you want is contained inside the data array. So just loop through that array instead and it should work.

```
$.each(response.data,function(index, v){
    //now v.buyItemTempId and other properties exist
}
```

Comment: that give  jquery.js:358
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Alright, can you paste the url you are hitting for the ajax request in a new browser window? Make sure to include any extra parameters with that url. This should print the full json response to your window. Then could you copy that json response and edit your question with it. Because you are copying things from the console inspector, the formatting is all messed up. I want to see the *entire* response. I know this is an issue with the way you are looping through the data vs. the structure the data is in, but until I can see the entire structure of the response, I can't really help.